# How to detect when a user has finished scrolling via a trackpad or mousewheel?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect when a user has **finished** scrolling.

When dragging a scrollbar the old fashioned way, a `mouseup` event fires when the user lets go

When swiping on a touchscreen a `touchend` or `MSPointerUp` fires.

But if the user is scrolling via a mousewheel or some other trackpad gesture then what event[s] can be used to establish that the scrolling intention has ended?

I could do this with timeout mechanism in the `scroll` event handler, but ideally a single event signalling the end of the scroll is what I want.

Comment: I don't *think* such an event exists, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10817088/932282 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3515446/932282

Comment: Thanks for duplicates. I never seem to get good suggestions when composing the subject! Solutions accepted there are the timeout mechanisms I mentioned.